# Where is FxCop in 64bit version of Windows SDK?

Tags: .net, windows, sdk

I found the Microsoft instructions on how to setup the fxCop, I installed Windows SDK for Windows 7 but I cannot find the folder with FXCop.

Here's a fragment from Microsoft's instructions:

FxCop Installation Instructions

1. Download the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 version 7.1.
2. Run %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\FXCop\FxCopSetup.exe to install FxCop.

Comment: Windows SDK has many setup options, run the setup again and make sure you select proper components to be installed.

Comment: I haven't got version 7 but version 6 is in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\FXCop` and it's an `msi` file rather than `exe.

Comment: Did you do a search from the relative root of the SDK directory?

Comment: I have it, same version.  Impossible to guess why you don't.  Beware of a 64 bit operating system, it is in c:\program files, not c:\program files (x86).

Comment: for me, `FxCopSetup` is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\FXCop` on Windows 7 64 bit Professional

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP: I just installed the 7.1 version of the SDK on Windows 7/64 today, first from the web installer, then again from the ISO, and there's no FxCopSetup or FxCop* directory in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin - or anywhere in the 7.1 tree. I do have one in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\FXCop, but that just installs the old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an omission from the 64-bit version of the 7.1 SDK installer. It was missing for me as well after I ran the install, but then I installed the 32-bit version of the SDK on a VM that I have and then copied the FxCopSetup.exe file from the bin directory of that image to the 64-bit machine and ran it, and so far FxCop appears to be working fine on the 64-bit box.

Comment: If it was an omission at the time of your answer in August 2011, you'll be glad to learn it's still an omission almost two years after in April 2013...

Comment: Have just dug it out of the current 64 bit SDK at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\FXCop` so this answer is no longer current.

Comment: Still missing in 64-bit SDK on some installs. The SDK installs differently based on what is already on the system, so it may be dependent on your system config whether the FxCop directory in `v7.1\Bin` gets made.

Answer (score 21):

I also ran into the same issue using the 64-bit version. I worked around the issue by extracting the FxCop installer from within the SDK ISO, as shown here: http://ruthlesslyhelpful.net/2011/06/09/liberate-fxcop-10-0/

Just in case that link is not available, the steps include:

1. Download the [Windows SDK ISO for Windows 7 and .NET 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35aeda01-421d-4ba5-b44b-543dc8c33a20&displaylang=en)
2. Open the ISO using 7-Zip and navigate to
       Microsoft\SDK\Setup\WinSDKNetFxTools\cab1.cab
3. Within cab1.cab, look for a file that starts with
   WinSDK_FxCopSetup.exe, and extract it.
4. Rename the extracted file to an .exe extension, and you're done.

Comment: Inside the ISO the cab1.cab is now located at Setup\WinSDKNetFxTools, but works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

> Where is FxCop in 64bit version of Windows SDK?

Since FxCop 10.0 is distributed as part of Windows 7 SDK, you have to do some download and extractions to install it on servers which are not running Windows 7. You can follow [instructions](http://ruthlesslyhelpful.net/2011/06/09/liberate-fxcop-10-0/) to extract the setup file.

**If you are in a hurry, you can download the [standalone installer on Codeplex.](https://fxcopinstaller.codeplex.com)**

There has not been any modification to the original binary file. You can check the file size, version # and the signature of the assembly to verify its authenticity.